# Extracting all lines from a file that are not commented out in a shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to extract lines from certain files that do not begin with # (commented out). How would I run through a file, ignore everything with a # in front of it, but copy each line that does not start with a # into a different file.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler: `grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: This one works well, I used:

cat file1.txt | sed -e '/\s*\#/d' > file2.txt

Comment: @Danny, that will delete any line with a hash, including a line like: `echo "this line # has a hash"`. You need to anchor your pattern to the beginning of the line. Also, useless use of cat. Try this: `sed -e '/^\s*#/d' file1.txt > file2.txt`

Comment: @Glenn, that works until there is any whitespace before the hash mark. If something is tabbed in and commented, it doesn't remove that line. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Danny, what version of grep are you running: `grep --version`

Comment: @Danny, dunno, works for me: lines with spaces or tabs at the beginning of the line followed by a hash are removed. Try running your input through `od -c` to see what the offending characters are that the `[[:space:]]*` regex does not match.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you're using Unix/Linux shell and the available Unix toolkit of commands AND that you want to keep a copy of the original file.

```
cp file file.orig
mv file file.fix
sed '/^[      ]*#/d' file.fix > file
rm file.fix
```

Or if you've got a nice shiny new GNU sed that all be summarized as

```
cp file file.orig
sed -i '/^[      ]*#/d' file
```

In both cases, the regexp in the sed command is meant to be `[spaceCharTabChar]`
So you saying, delete any line that begins with an (optional space or tab chars) #, but print everything else.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `grep -v '^/[    ]*#/' file` is a little simpler.

Comment: `grep -v` works too. Also, many seds support the `[[:space:]]` syntax advocated by @pulsar, so try substituting that first.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v ^\# file > newfile
grep -v ^\# file | grep -v ^$ > newfile
```

Not fancy regex, but I provide this method to Jr. Admins as it helps with understanding of pipes and redirection.